# Delete UICollectionViewCell with UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` that I populate from my Image Library.

I want to be able to delete a cell from the collection by using a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` on the cell. The `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is working.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"Selected cell = %ld",(long)indexPath.item);

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(activateDeletionMode:)];
longPress.delegate = self;
[collectionView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

}

- (void)activateDeletionMode:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gr
{
if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
NSLog(@"delete mode");
}
}
```

Comment: change in **UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan** into **UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded** and add **minimumTimeDuration also**, finally add some code of your `cell for Row`

Answer (score 0):

In your case try this

```
    - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    NSLog(@"Selected cell = %ld",(long)indexPath.item);

     UILongPressGestureRecognizer * longPres 
       = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(activateDeletionMode:)];
   longPres.minimumPressDuration = .5; //seconds
   longPres.delegate = self;
    [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer: longPres];


    }

    - (void)activateDeletionMode:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gr
    {
    if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
    NSLog(@"delete mode");
    }
    }
```

in other case you can try this

**//add long press gesture to collectionView**

```
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpress 
       = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongpressMethod:)];
    longpress.minimumPressDuration = .5; //seconds
   longpress.delegate = self;
    [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer: longpress];
}
```

then handle  the action

```
-(void) handleLongpressMethod:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        return;
    }
    CGPoint pt = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collectionView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:pt];
    if (indexPath == nil){
        NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");            
    } else {
        // get the cell at indexPath (the one you long pressed)
        UICollectionViewCell* cell =
        [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        // work  with the cell


    }
```

delete

```
 [self.youritemarray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPathh];
 [collectionView reloadData];
```

Comment: @Len van Zyl let me know if issue ?

Comment: the Long Press I used is working fine, I want to delete a cell when long press is activated , soo the deleting process is my question

Comment: [self.youritemarray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPathh]; use this